# For Loop in print statement is giving generator funtion as output

Tags: python

This is my program I can't understand what is wrong with this program.
I want to Print the pattern shown in the given sample output

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print(i for x in list(range(0,i)))
```

Sample Input:

`5`

Sample output:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

Output Given By the program:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7feb4598cdb0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7feb4598cdb0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7feb4598cdb0>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7feb4598cdb0>
```

Comment: I believe you need to wrap the loop with `[` and `]`, ie `print([i for x in list(range(0,i))])`

Comment: `print("".join(str(i) for x in list(range(0,i))))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```or-tag-here
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print([i for x in range(0,i)])
```

Generators in python are defined with `()`, make sure you use the brackets, to make a list comprehension.